# Where is java.time in Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android-studio

According to Android Studio documentation:

> Android Studio 3.0 introduces built-in support for Java 8 libraries

But a huge improvement in Java 8 is the use of the new **java.time** library.  For now, this library seems not included in this version.

So my question: I'm I wrong ?  If not, is there any workaround possible to use this library in Android applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Java 8 language feature support running in Android Studio, check these four things:

1. Make sure you are running the latest version of Android Studio 3.0
2. Ensure you are using the embedded JDK[image: Embedded JDK setting]
3. Update your the source and
   target compatibility versions to 1.8 in your project structure.[image: Target Compatibility & minSdkVersion]
4. Ensure you minSdkVersion is 24 (or 26/'O' depending on which method
   you want to use in the class)

Once your project complies with those settings, you can add libraries such as: *import java.time.LocalDateTime;* to your project. Check out this page for more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html