# Can't access java.time in Android Studio

Tags: android, java-8

I have been using java.time package in eclipse for sometime and it worked great. However, Android Studio doesn't seem to have that feature built in.

I'm using the embedded jdk which turns out to be jdk 8 after some digging, my gradle version is 4.4, my android plugin version is 3.1.0, my minimum sdk version is API 24, both my source and target compatibility is 1.8 and my build tools version is 27.0.3.

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197043/where-is-java-time-in-android-studio-3-0) and [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) before but they don't seem to help much.

Does anyone know much about this? I'm kinda a beginner for Android but I've done a lot of Java programming.

Comment: show your code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes in `java.time` and its sub-packages are part of Java 8. Some Java 8 classes, including `java.time`, were added in API Level 26, and so they will show up if your `compileSdkVersion` is 26 or higher (and it should be that by now). However, you will get warnings pointing out that you cannot use them going all the way back to your `minSdkVersion` of 24. Your choices are:

- Raise your `minSdkVersion` to 26, or
- Do not use the `java.time` classes (e.g., stick to Java 7-and-below solutions, use Joda Time)